# install pdo sqlite driver

Tags: sqlite, pdo

how to install pdo sqlite drivers to enable onserver support

Comment: Maybe if you rewrite your sentence and include a question mark it would get a proper question.
Do you have any shell access to the server or is this just webspace? What does phpinfo(); look like?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand the question, you want to know how to enable `PDO SQLite` access. Depending on the version of your PHP configuration, you may need to select different options, but assuming PHP 5.3.x, you should edit the `php.ini` to include the following libraries (for Windows - similar libs with different extension on *nix) in the `extension=lib.dll` (or `extension=lib.so`):

- php_pdo.dll
- php_pdo_sqlite.dll
- php_sqlite.dll

This assumes they are available on your server and you can edit the PHP.ini config. If you cannot then you may have to ask your host provider to do this for you (which they may...).

Comment: this helped me, thanks a lot! A little amendment to make it more clear: on *nix you should edit `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` or the `.../cli/php.ini` and add these `...so` lines, then restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

SQLite Functions (PDO_SQLITE)

Introduction

PDO_SQLITE is a driver that implements the PHP Data Objects (PDO) interface to enable access to SQLite 3 databases.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php